# Image files encryption, which part should be encrypted without breaking files

Tags: image, image-processing, encryption, png, jpeg

I have a question about image processing and encryption data. 
Let's say we have PNG file, which I want to encrypt and the question is which part of the file could be encrypted to not broke it.

According to documentation, PNG file looks like that: "IHDR....1...IDAT....2....IDAT....3....IDAT....4....IEND"
Is it ok to just encrypt parts 2,3,4? Because when I did it, file is broken. I thought that leaving IHDR is enough, but it isn't.
Simmilar thing with JPEG file, which parts could be encrypted?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The IDAT sections contain compressed pixel data. If you encrypt them, then it won't be possible to decompress them properly. Also each chunk of a PNG file contains a CRC32 checksum, so you're probably causing file validation errors when you attempt to read the file back.

Comment: Actually I am not compressing pixel data I want to encode it using some cryptographical algorithm.

Comment: Then just encrypt the whole file. There's no sensible way of encrypting the image data inside a PNG or JPEG file that leaves you with valid PNG/JPEG data.

Comment: Is it any file format which I could encrypt in that way? To make image visible but encrypted?

Comment: Well, yes. But it would have to be one that stores the pixel data without any compression, which means your files are going to be rather large. The easiest to work with is a binary [PPM image file](https://my.eng.utah.edu/~cs5610/ppm.html), which consists of a short header followed by a stream of bytes corresponding to the R, G and B values of each pixel in each row from top to bottom. Windows BMP files can also be uncompressed, but they sometimes include padding bytes at the end of each row.